# Can I get resource String from resource id on Android?

Tags: android

Can I get resource 'String' from resource id on Android?

eg)

```
int id = R.drawable.abc;
String ret = getMyResourceString(id);
```

I need ret is "abc" or "drawable.abc" or "R.drawable.abc"

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two method to get String from resource `getResources().getResourceEntryName(int id)` or `getResource().getResourceName(int id)` they have different output, choose what helps you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get resource string from drawable but yes you can get it from strings.xml file using - `getResources().getString(R.string.id)`